# Problema al consultar API laravel con React JS

Tags: reactjs

Buenas tardes querida comunidad, Disculpen necesito su ayuda tengo 2 días buscando una solución pero aun no puedo resolverlo...

Tengo un FrontEnd hecho con React JS y estoy tratando de conectarme a mi API de Laravel pero me sale el siguiente error

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Eso en el mejor de los casos estoy trabajando con Axios y antes de que me retornara el 404 me decía esto **Uncaught (in promise)**

Ya no se que mas hacer agradezco su ayuda por favor, aca les dejo el componente de React que esta haciendo la consulta.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


const baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/";

export default class Test extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      opcion: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get(baseUrl + 'api/opciones/list')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.setState({ opcion: response.data })
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log(error)
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">

        <h3>Laravel y React APIRest</h3>
        <hr />
        {JSON.stringify(this.state.opcion)}
        <table className="table table-bordered order-table ">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Opcion</th>
              <th>Nombre</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id="bodytable">
            {this.renderList()}
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    );
  }

  renderList() {

    return this.state.opcion.map((data) => {

      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{data.opcion}</td>
          <td>{data.nombre}</td>

        </tr>
      )

    })

  }
}
```

Agradezco toda la ayuda que me puedan prestar si tengo algún tipo de error o si por otra parte saben como hacer una petición de manera diferente

Comment: Podrías poner el código PHP? Ya probaste tu web service por separado?

Comment: Qué tienes en web.php o api.php? Declaraste la ruta? A eso se refiere el comentario anterior también.

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucioné agregué cors a las cabeceras de Laravel el problema creo q era por las conexiones o peticiones a sitios http y no a https agregué las cabeceras y se soluciono

Comment: Sos el mismo usuario que pregunto? perdiste acceso a tu cuenta? avisame y lo arreglamos. usa @gbianchi para comunicarte. por otra parte, esta respuesta es de muy baja calidad, no se entiende que hiciste porque no lo estas explicando, parece solo un comentario...